# How to convert an SSIS Date Variable to String In order to return the 2 digit month value?

Tags: ssis

I have an SSIS variable @[User::SelectedDate] from which I want to return the 2 digit month value to use in an expression. How do you do this?

(DT_STR,4,1252) DATEPART ("yy",@[User::SelectedDate]) returns the year as text, but how do you get the two digit month value?

I tried (DT_STR,4,1252) DATEPART("mm",@[User::SelectedDate]) to return the month but it does not work. It returns "1" while the value is 2021-10-31, so no idea what I am doing wrong. Important to add that I need the two digit value, so "02" for February, not "2"

Note: The variable is not the current date. I have seen many similar questions where getdate() is used as a solution. This wouldn't work in this case, as the date is selected from a database table

Any help will be much appreciated.
Have already wasted an hour on this.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble with datepart. you can always use script component or task.

Component:

```
string strMonth = Variables.SelectedDate.ToString("MM"); //Note capital MM as mm means minutes
```

Task:

```
string strMonth = Dts.Variables["SelectedDate"].Value.ToString("MM");
```

Comment: i actually know that i could save the two digit month as a text variable, but really wanted to do it in a more elegant way. Hence the question. thanks anyway!

Comment: i thought doing this was simple for the experts but apparently not

Comment: there's nothing wrong with your syntax. are you sure User::SelectedDate is what you think it is

Comment: yes, there was nothing wrong. the result from the variable was not what i thought, as you correctly pointed out